# Overwrite a table using results from a query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using Sqlite3. What is the most efficient way to:

1. Execute a query to join two tables t1 and t2. The query is designed to keep all of the columns from t1, and just add columns from t2. It will either keep all rows (left outer join) or just keep the matching rows.
2. Using the result, update t1 in the database to look exactly like the results of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select a.*, b.hostname, b.mac
from tablea a left join 
tableb b on a.ip_address = b.ip
```

Comment: i'm unsure what I would write in place of a.value = b.value

Comment: Give me an example of the data you have and I will show you

Comment: t1 columns: ip_address, cpus, OS
t2 columns: ip, hostname, mac

the query should update t1 to include hostname and mac 
(where t1.ip_address = t2.ip)

Comment: thanks Daniel, I think I chose the wrong word (update). When I say "update" the table. I am looking not to replace column values... but to add 2 columns to t1 and insert information where there is a match in t2... I  don't want to replace any information

Comment: that's the ticket! is there a way I use this query result to update the table t1?

Comment: You just said you didn't want to update table1 - you wanted to add to it right? in that case just write the select to a temp table, drop your original table, and then recreate from the temp table

Comment: Ok that method, I just wanted to be sure that I was using sql as intended. thanks for your persistance